# PhantomJs 2.0.0 - viewportSize / zoomFactor not working for PDF

Tags: phantomjs, pdf-generation

I am trying to export html to pdf with Phantomjs. Everything is working well, except the size of the html objects in the PDF. 
There is not effect at all when I use viewportSize or zoomFactor.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 800, height: 600};
page.zoomFactor  = 2;
page.open("http://www.google.com", function start(status) {
    page.render('test.pdf');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue in 2.0.0
See https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12685

Using PhantomJs Version 1.9.8 works well. See https://gist.github.com/julionc/7476620 for easy installation

Comment: Try the github ticket: 
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12685

Answer (score 1):

This tweak can be used to fix this :

**Comment** below code in `rasterize.js`

```
/*if (system.args.length > 4) {
        page.zoomFactor = system.args[4];
    }
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
            phantom.exit(1);
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                page.render(output);
                phantom.exit();
            }, 200);
        }
    });*/
```

Add below `code` at the same place.

```
page.zoomFactor = parseFloat('0.4');
     page.open(address, function (status) {
            if (status !== 'success') {
                phantom.exit(1);
            } else {
                window.setTimeout(function () {
          page.evaluate(function(zoom) {
            return document.querySelector('body').style.zoom = zoom;
        }, page.zoomFactor);
                    page.render(output);
                    phantom.exit();
                }, 200);
            }
        });
```

Comment: As PhantomJS has stopped development, really opening a ticket wouldn't solve anything. This might be a work around, but works well. 
Only thing is that I would recommend adding:
    if (system.args.length > 4) {
        page.zoomFactor = parseFloat(system.args[4]);
    }
So that the user can still set a zoom factor.